# Iterator has .next() - is there a way to get the previous element instead of the next one?

Tags: java, collections, iterator

I have an Iterator that I use on a HashMap, and I save and load the iterator.
is there a way to get the previous key in the HashMap with Iterator? (java.util.Iterator)

#### Update

I save it as an attribute in a Red5 connection and then load it back to continue working where i stopped.

#### Another update

I'm iterating through the keyset of the HashMap

Comment: Beware: a `HashMap` has no fixed ordering and may change depending on object's hashcode. If you want an ordered `Map`, consider `TreeMap` (auto-sort on keys) or `LinkedHashMap` (insertion order).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not directly, as others pointed out, but if you e.g. need to access one previous element you could easily save that in a separate variable.

```
T previous = null;
for (Iterator<T> i = map.keySet().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
    T element = i.next();

    // Do something with "element" and "previous" (if not null)

    previous = element;
}
```

Comment: ...although I can't really think in what case this would be useful when iterating through *randomly ordered* HashMap keys

Comment: thanks for pointing out that the hashmap keys are randomly ordered.

Comment: @ufk: For further info, don't miss BalusC's comment on the question!

Answer (score 42):

You can use    `ListIterator`    instead of `Iterator`. 
ListIterator has `previous()` and `hasPrevious()` methods.

Answer (score 14):

It sounds like you want the array semantics more akin to a [ListIterator](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) rather than those provided by the Iterator interface.  The easiest way to acquire such a thing is likely to construct a list ( from the key-set (`LinkedList<K> keyList = new LinkedList<K>(map.keySet())`), then use a ListIterator manually instead of a regular Iterator or foreach.

For very simple cases of needing to remember consecutive items, the simplest way to handle this is to store the previous Key in a local variable and update it at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 3):

No, an [`Iterator<E>`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) defines only 3 methods:

```
boolean hasNext()
E next()
void remove()
```

You can of course implement your own iterator.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you only access an element using `next()`. However it's *sort of* a matter of terminology. Once you call `next()` this *is* the current element.

Unless the problem is you need to see two consecutive items in the collection each iteration, in which case a simple variable would seem easiest.

Answer (score 1):

Although `Set` doesn't provide a method for a reverse iterator, [`Deque`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) does. You can use [`descendingIterator()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#descendingIterator()) for an iterator in *reverse* order and [`iterator()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#iterator()), for an iterator in *forwards* order.

(You can create a `Deque` from a `Set` via `Deque<T> deque = new LinkedList<T>(set)`, where `set` is your `Set` and `T` the generic type you're using.)

Comment: +1 for applying "know and use the libraries". Not sure if this would be the best solution to OP's root problem (whatever that is) though.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately `Iterator`s are not fully suited for your task.

Why not create a `List` from your `Set` (via, eg, `List list = new LinkedList(set)`) and iterate by using a standard indexed for-loop? That way you know the previous element is at `i - 1`.

Comment: Beware that random-access into a LinkedList is deadly slow at large data sizes.  For Linked data structures you pretty much always want to prefer an Iterator.

Answer (score 0):

using iterator, No you dont have an option to get a previous key value. it has only hasNext() and next() methods.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. The Iterator interface has no method to get the previous element.

But what you can do is - a little bit rubbish-  creating a `List<Entry<Integer, YourObjectType>>` where the `Integer`-value represents the hash-code of the key-object. Then you can do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
{
    YourObjectType current = list.get(i).getValue();
    YourObjectType previous = (i == 0 ? null : list.get(i - 1).getValue());
    // Do whatever you want
}
```

I know this is very rubbish, but it is possible

Answer (score 0):

Make your own Iterator:

```
public class EnhancedIterator<E> implements Iterator<E>{
    private List<E> list;
    private int indexSelected=-1;
    public EnhancedIterator(List<E> list){
        this.list=list;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return indexSelected<list.size()-1;
    }

    @Override
    public E next() {
        indexSelected++;
        return current();
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        list.remove(indexSelected);
    }
    public void remove(int i){
        list.remove(i);
        if(i<indexSelected){
            indexSelected--;
        }
    }
    public E previous(){
        indexSelected--;
        return current();
    }
    public E current(){
        return list.get(indexSelected);
    }
    public E get(int i){
        return list.get(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you've got a `List` in the first place, you should just invoke `List.listIterator()`. It's easier and uses a standard type.